# Add expires header for all files except specific files

Tags: .htaccess, caching, expires-header

I'm trying to add expires headers to all files except some specific files. In fact, I'm using a caching tool, that adds the following code to my htaccess:

```
# BEGIN LBCWpFastestCache
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/webp A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/ico A2592000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A2592000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Expires "max-age=2592000, public"
Header unset ETag
Header set Connection keep-alive
FileETag None
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END LBCWpFastestCache
```

I want to make an exception for two different images on my page. Let their names be file-a and file-b, here is what I tried:

I put this code after the code from the plugin.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(file-a|file-b)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hour"
</FilesMatch>
```

Since that didn't work, I also tried putting it before the code, which didn't work either.

Then I tried manipulating the `FilesMatch` part of the code added by the plugin, so that it excludes my files.

```
<FilesMatch "(?!.*/(file-a|file-b))(\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$)">
```

Didn't work either.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to assert the banned files names since the following capture group can sill match the allowed file extensions. You should be able to solve it using a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
^((?!\/file-a|file-b).)*(\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wBDVgz/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookbehind regex search.
Check out this [regex101 playground](https://regex101.com/r/GiPSCN/2)

```
<FilesMatch "(?<!file-a|file-b)(\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$)">
```